# ontoggle sidebar - col width changes - but content doesn't - sublime video JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, video, twitter-bootstrap-3

The page with content loads perfectly. 
Content:

- video (rightside)
- information about the video (leftside)

When I do these steps, it doesn't:

1. click on sidebar toggler (opens the sidebar)
2. the col-md-.. changes automaticly (wich is nice)
3. but the content (sublimevideo) doesn't (so it still has the same width)

When I resize the window of the browser, the video resizes.

**My question:**

How can I capture the event of changing the width of the div where my video is in?
I would launch the function resize when this div changed.